# Getting all rows for a large grouping in CQL when the group's ID can change

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, cql3

As an example, let's say I want to store books and which libraries they are in.  I could make a table like this:

```
create table book (
  id uuid,
  created timestamp,
  title text,
  library_id uuid,

  primary key (id)  
);
```

If I wanted to get a listing of all books in a given library, I could make a materialized view like this:

```
create materialized view book_per_library as
  select *
  from book
  where library_id is not null
  and id is not null
  primary key (library_id, id);
```

I think there are some problems that come up with that schema and I'm unsure how to solve them.

**Problem 1. Too many books for one node along with slow querying**

To make this example equivalent to the data I'm actually working with, I could potentially have billions of books in a single library.  If my partition key is the library_id (in either the table or the materialized view), I would max out what can be stored on the node which has that partition key.  One possible solution I found could be to partition the data based on the created timestamp like this:

```
create table book (
  id uuid,
  created timestamp,
  title text,
  library_id uuid,
  date text,

  primary key (id, library_id)  
);

create materialized view book_per_library as
  select *
  from book
  where library_id is not null
  and date is not null
  and id is not null
  primary key ((library_id, date), id);
```

This is based on readings such as https://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling where the date column is something like “2013-04-03”.  Then I would have to run a separate query over each day.  For my actual data, I might even need to split that into each hour to still allow a single node to store it all.  My data can added in very large bursts (e.g. millions) in a short period of time such as an hour.  Or my data can be added drop-by-drop (e.g. a single or a few at a time) every once and a while.  Thus it's not a constant stream of data.

Anyways, wouldn't the querying here be a slow process?  I could potentially have to run thousands of queries to cover the span of many years just to get the list of books in that single library.  Also, how do I know what dates actually have data?

I guess I'm basically trying to find a way to avoid having to use something like spark to read the entire book table because I don't want to read the rows for all libraries, just the one I care about.  I'm also trying to find a way to avoid having to run queries for dates that don't have any data because that seems like wasted time.  One thought is to find a way to have cassandra track which dates have data for each library so I know which partition keys to even query for.  Maybe have a counter table where I store a count of books for each date value like “2013-04-03”.  It would be a two-step process to read all of those counts for the given library and then only run the main query for dates that have a count > 0.  Is that a viable solution?  Are there better options?

**Problem 2. I must be able to move the books to a different library, i.e. I must be able to change the library_id**

As a requirement, I must be able to move books to different libraries.  As far as I understand, that means I cannot have the library_id as either a partition key column or clustering column.  If I did, then “moving” the book to another library would require me to delete it from the current library and then add a new record to the new library.  Is that accurate?  Are there better ways of associating rows in a table with a group but also provide the ability to change that grouping?

**Overall Question**

What is the best practice for a situation like this where I want to get all rows of a table associated with some “Group ID” like the library_id and I could potentially have billions of them for each group and I need to be able to change that association?

I'm planning on using cassandra 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Cassandra is not the best tool for such types of workloads. Indeed, Cassandra is fantastic at getting a few rows from a partition, even in a huge dataset, but fetching billions of rows all together really is an anti-pattern.

---

### But nothing is lost

Your initial data model seems wrong to me. You modeled a "library collection" and then using the materialized view you implement a look-up table. I don't know the reasoning behind this, but if you directly implement the "materialized" table yourself you end-up with the same thing:

```
create table books_by_library_id (
  library_id int,
  book_id uuid,
  book_created timestamp,
  book_title text,
  book_date text,

  primary key (library_id, book_title)
);
```

Now, your **Problem 1** is **real**. You shouldn't have more than say 10k or 20k records on each partition, because querying for that partition put stress on one node only. Currently your partition consists of the `library_id` field only. You need to find something else that splits data into multiple partitions, and then get your data back with multiple queries, reassembling data into your application. That would allow your cluster to easily survive a fetch of billions of rows, because you'd issue multiple queries, each one being processed by a distinct node. Basically, you "manually" orchestrate the cluster to fetch what you want.

What can be done to split data into multiple partitions? A typical approach is to "bucketing" your data. In your example, you can easily "divide" each library in (at least) 26 buckets, one per alphabetic letter from A to Z:

```
create table books_by_library_id_and_initials (
  library_id int,
  book_title_initials text,
  book_id uuid,
  book_created timestamp,
  book_title text,
  book_date text,

  primary key ((library_id, book_title_initials), book_title)
);
```

To fetch all your books belonging to the `library_id=2` you need to issue 26 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM books_by_library_id_and_initials WHERE library_id=2 AND book_title_initials='a';
SELECT * FROM books_by_library_id_and_initials WHERE library_id=2 AND book_title_initials='b';
...
SELECT * FROM books_by_library_id_and_initials WHERE library_id=2 AND book_title_initials='z';
```

Moreover, this would still allow you to fetch a book directly with:

```
SELECT * FROM books_by_library_id_and_initials 
WHERE library_id=2 
  AND book_title_initials='c' 
  AND book_title = 'Cassandra from Zero to Hero';
```

If you are afraid that dividing 5 billions rows in 26 buckets is not enough, you can add another letter to the partition key, going up to 676 buckets (and then issuing 676 queries), or another two letters, going up to 17576 buckets (and then issuing 17576 queries sigh!).

With these high numbers, it would make sense to track the number of books in a particular bucket with a dedicated table. If this table tells you that no books are present in a bucket you don't issue the query. You query the partition otherwise.

```
CREATE TABLE my_counters (
  library_id int,
  book_title_initials text,
  books_count counter,
  PRIMARY KEY (library_id, book_title_initials)
);

SELECT counter FROM my_counters 
 WHERE library_id = 2 
   AND book_title_initials='cas';
```

I don't think you can go further than this, however.

About your **Problem 2**, instead, you'll need to delete the book from one library and recreate it in another. No escapes from that because you can't update the values of a primary key.

HTH.

Answer (score -1):

What you describing is totally looks like an index databse on top of your library tables. I think you can put something like [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) into good use. Especially if you want to have an ability to change row association rules "on-the-fly" - you would change index structure, but not library data.

Also, DataStax Enterprise have [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/features.html) [support](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html). But, it might be an overkill in your situation cause you don't need full-text search and stuff.